# Ограничить массив со смещением

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть массив в виде

```
$arr = [
            ["name" => "Alex", "date" => "19.02.1990"],
            ["name" => "Smit", "date" => "24.12.1992"],
            ["name" => "Jack", "date" => "1.06.1988"],
];
```

Мне нужно ограничить его. То-есть чтобы было не более 100 ключей. Если массив достигает 100 значений то новое значение добавляется в начало а последнее удаляется. Как это сделать я знаю, но где-то видел код в пару строчек когда. Подскажите его пожалуйста, не могу найти. Либо как сделать лучше?

Ответ на ответ ниже. Так будет правильнее

```
if (count($arr) > 100) {
    $arr = array_merge($new, $arr);
    $arr = array_slice($arr, 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: так вынеси свою реализацию в метод и пользуйся в одну строчку кода)

Answer (score 2):

Тут зависит от того, как вы новые данные добавляете и от массивов... Можно как-то так это делать:

```
$array = array("1" => "1",  
            "2" => "2", 
            "3" => "3", 
            "4" => "4", 
            "5" => "5", 
            "6" => "6", 
            "7" => "7"
          );          
$new = array("8" => "8",  
                "9" => "9", 
                "10" => "10"
              );

function array_limit($arr,$added_arr,$count){
    $arr = array_merge($arr,$added_arr);
    $elems_count = count($added_arr);
    $arr = array_slice($arr, 0+$elems_count, $count+$elems_count);
    return $arr;
}
$new_array = array_limit($array,$new,5);
var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

чем вам не нравится такой вариант?

```
if (count($array) > 100) {
    array_unshift($element);
    array_pop($array); 
}
```

Comment: Не самая лучшая идея. А если у меня будет 2  новых элемента в массиве либо больше, а array_pop уберет только один. И array_unshift с ассоциативными массивами по моему не работает.

Comment: @VikiMayson, надо было уточнить в вопросе, что возможно добавление нескольких значений одновременно.  `новое значение добавляется в начало а последнее удаляется`

Comment: @VikiMayson, и в вашем примере `array_merge($new, $array)` $new случайно не вида ['key' => 'value'], как и элементы в массиве $arr? если да, тогда у вас будет массив вида [['key' => 'value'], 'key' => 'value']. если же нет, то дополните вопрос, т.к. я не совсем понимаю что требуется.